# Problemas en Report Viewer en Visual Studio 2017

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc

hasta hace poco trabajaba con VS2015 y podía crear reportes con report viewer con normalidad y todo funcionaba normal, ahora empece a trabajar con Visual Studio 2017 y tengo problemas con los reportes, les explico:

En caso de tener un reporte sin parámetros ni orígenes de datos todo funciona con normalidad, pero ete tipo de reportes creo que no le sirven a nadie.
He aquí el meollo, cuando agrego aunque sea un simple parámetro string, simplemente salta una excepción como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien tiene el mismo problema o alguna idea de como solucionarle se lo agradecería mucho al igual que muchos en mi lugar.

Agradezco de antemano, saludos cordiales a todos.

Comment: es un sencillo cambio de parametro en tu generador de reportes, te esta diciendo que estas usando una funcion que no existe, supongo que es porque usaste el mismo proyecto del visual 2015, en la opcion propiedades del proyecto, cambia alguna opcion que diga windows 8 sdk por windows 10 sdk

Comment: Encontre la respuesta aqui:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCr29SWbg5g

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tendrías que "volver" a crear el reporte o abrirlo en la nueva versión del visual studio, eso es normal cuando cambias de versión. La versión de Report Viewer para VS 2015 es la 13 creo y para esta es la 14, es incompatibilidad en el archivo xml que genera el ReportViewer.

Answer (score 0):

Si puedes abrir el reporte veras que tiene el namespaces (xmlns) que tiene esto

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition"
xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">....
```

Para este tipo de reportes te conviene tener el ultimo ReportViewer.

Para eso tienes que descargarlo desde nuget, por ejemplo para webforms

- [Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms)

Utilizas VS2017 tambien para armar tus reportes? Yo te recomendaria [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2016 Report Builder](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53613). Pero debe ser que es costumbre de varios años.

La ultima actualizacion de SSDT  (SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio) trae la parte de Reporting, ademas de proyectos de base datos, analysis services integration services. Si quieres trabajar dentro de Visual Studio 2017 vas a tener que instalarlo

- (Download and install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio)[https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017]

PD: Cuando instalas SSDT te pide para instalar en una nueva instancia de VS o en la que tienes.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia